# angular-ui bootstrap tooltip issue

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-bootstrap

For some reason with the way we structured the page, the tooltip is not working.

main.html

```
<div class="main-navigation">
   <div rt-tool-menus-"menus" selected="selectedMenus" tooltip="{{appController.displayName}}"></div>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('abc')
  .controller('abcController',.....

  self.menus=[
      {
         heading: 'Head1',
         active: false,
         route: 'head1'
      },
      {
         heading: 'Head2',
         active: false,
         route: 'head2'
         tooltip: 'head2' // tried, doesnt work
      }];

     self.selectedMenus = []'
     self.tooltip = appConfig.displayName; // tried not working
```

what would be the right approach to show tooltip with the correct header, and location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `appConfig` is (not visible in your snippet) but you have to add the text you want to show in the tooltip to an instance variable of the controller if you're using `controllerAs` or a `$scope` variable.

Please have a look at the code below or in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/vvtrus84/).

It's not clear what `rt-tool-menus` is. Is it a custom directive?

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($tooltipProvider) {
 $tooltipProvider.options({placement: 'bottom'});
})
.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    
    this.displayName = 'Hello there';
});
```

```css
.main-navigation {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    <div class="main-navigation">
       <div rt-tool-menus-"menus" selected="selectedMenus" tooltip="{{mainCtrl.displayName}}">Hover me to show tooltip!!!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```